# How to insert a randomly generated number into an email using html with a button

Tags: button, random, html-email

I am very new to coding and would like to know if the below is possible:

I need to create an html email template with buttons that would essentially do the following:

I need an 'ACCEPT' button that would, when clicked on in the email, generate a unique/random 4-6 digit number for the client and also automatically send that number back to the sender as confirmation that the client has approved/accepted the quote. Almost like an OTP.

This number will serve as a confirmation number so I need it to be static, and for the client to therefor only be able to use the button once.

I will also be adding a 'REJECT' button which will cancel the client's appointment, but I would like to know if there is a way for it to then render the 'ACCEPT' button unusable?

Comment: The reason you've never seen anything more complicated than links in emails is that email clients do not execute JS. What you are asking for is simply not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The client cannot do this on the email itself, however, you can certainly do this when you generate the email.

That is:

1. On the back-end system you are using add the numbers to the accept and reject buttons, e.g. `<a href="https://www.website.com?number=12345">Accept</a>`
2. Send the email(s)
3. Customer opens the email and clicks Accept, going to https://www.website.com?number=12345
4. This page needs to be configured to read that number and record it in the database

The exact way to do this is dependent on the system you are using